# Property alias cannot be accessed through another QML

Tags: sqlite, qt, qml

i was trying to make an app with Local Storage for the database and i want to display the data from the database to a listview in different QML file. i know i can make a property alias to the listview so i can access it from another file then append the query result. but when i hit the button to show the data it says that listViewKos was not define but it was already property alias

i did my best to keep the code short, some of the component might have been deleted due to it but appart from the problem i describe above everything works just fine.

@main.qml the JS is just a JS object where the data came from

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1
import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0
import "./Storage.js" as Storage


ApplicationWindow {
    id: applicationWindow
    width: 640
    height: 480
    property int kontrakanJumlahKamar
    property int kontrakanPrice
    property int kosPrice
    property string kosGenderType
    property alias kosloader: kosloader
    property var db

    Component.onCompleted: {
        db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("ngomahyuk", "1.0", "StorageDatabase", 1000000)

        db.transaction(function(tx){
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kos(namakos TEXT, alamat TEXT, thumbnail TEXT)');
        });

//        insert data for kos
        db.transaction(function(tx){
            for (var i = 0; i < Storage.kos.length; i++){
                try {
                   tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO kos (namakos, alamat, thumbnail) VALUES('"+Storage.kos[i].namakos+"','"+Storage.kos[i].alamat+"','"+Storage.kos[i].thumbnail+"'");
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    Button {
        id: button
        text: qsTr("Search")
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked:{
                if (textFieldHarga.text === ""){
                    kosPrice = 0
                } else {
                    kosPrice = parseInt(textFieldHarga.text)
                }
                kosGenderType = comboBoxGender.currentText
                kosloader.visible = true


                db.transaction(function(tx){
                    var rs = tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM kos WHERE gender = '"+kosGenderType+"' AND harga <= "+kosPrice);

                    if (rs.rows.length === 0){
                        alertDialogKos.open()
                    }else {
                        for (var i = 0; i < rs.rows.length; i++){
                            listViewKos.model.append({              //this is the one that suppose to be working
                               imagePath : rs.rows[i].thumbnail,
                               kosName : rs.rows[i].namakos,
                               kosAlamat : rs.rows[i].alamat,
                            })
                        }
                        kosloader.source = "Kos.qml"
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        MessageDialog{
          // messagedialog code deleted to keep it short
        }

        background: Rectangle {
         // deleted to keep it short
        }

        contentItem: Text {
            id: textItem
            text: "Search"
        }
    }
    Loader{
        id: kosloader
        width: 640
        height: 480
        opacity: 1
        clip: false
        visible: false
        active: false
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: ""
    }
}
```

@Kos.qml i use PageBackground.qml as a background

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

PageBackground {
    id: kos
    width: 640
    height: 480
    property alias listViewKos: listViewKos

    ListView {
        id: listViewKos
        x: 15
        y: 87
        width: 640
        height: 410
        clip: true
        model: ListModel{
//            need to be in for loop and data from database
        }


//        delegate listview template
        delegate: Item {
            height  : 195
            width   : 640
            Image {
                id: idthumbnail
                width: 235
                height: 165
                source: imagePath
            }

            Text {
                id: idnamakos
                x: 252
                y: 8
                text: kosName
            }

            Text {
                id: idalamat
                text: qsTr("Alamat            : " + kosAlamat)
            }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide working code, a [mcve] that we can run and test, not a spaghetti one. What is `kosloader`? How do you use/instantiate this Kos item in the main.qml?

Comment: sorry, i've edit the `kosloader`. if you want to look at the full project you can look at the [github repo](https://github.com/graceyudhaaa/ngomahyukv2/tree/model)

Comment: Ok, now it is clearer. The problem is that an loaded item exist in the scope of Loader and not accesible from outside. But the item itself can access outer items. So you have 3 options: create the list as a property out of the Loader and bind  `ListView.model` to it. another option is to add such property in the Loader. this property will be accessible from inside and from outside thew Loader. another option is `Loader.item`. But you have to check that item loaded. Also see your code -  you call to `listViewKos.model.append` when it doesn't exist and only then you load the item.